# "restore scroll position in android Paging adapter when user go to another fragment or activity from adapter" problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging, scroll-position

How can ı restore paging adapter item state when ı move to another fragment?
I tried article below but it didnt work.
https://medium.com/@florina.muntenescu

```
private fun loadData() {
        viewModel.apply {
            lifecycleScope.launch{
                viewModel.getMorePopularMovies().collectLatest { pagingData ->
                    dataAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, pagingData)

                }
            }
        }

    }

fun getMorePopularMovies() = Pager(
        PagingConfig(pageSize = 3)
) {
    VerticalMoviePagingSource(api, "Popular")
}.flow
```

Comment: I have the same problem, always go on top when back to fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `.cachedIn(viewModelScope)` in your viewModel code. For your case you will get:

```
  fun getMorePopularMovies() = Pager(
        PagingConfig(pageSize = 3)
) {
    VerticalMoviePagingSource(api, "Popular")
}.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

And try adding in your fragment:

```
adapter.stateRestorationPolicy =
        RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

If it doesn't work then there is another problem in your code, I guess.

Comment: it worked, thanks:)))